# Dynamic Action Redirect To Another Page In Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How Can I Redirect To Page By Dynamic Action.
FOR example i have Page item :P2_CODE and  value from application Items and some values from Substitution String then combine all like
&REP_URL.&REPORT=&REP_DIR.inv_prnt.rep&PRM_CODE=&GLB_CODE.&PRM_NUM=&P2_CODE.
and this all i want pass page no 3 there is page item :P3_VALUE how to do this sir
i dont want to do it by Branches only i want by DA.

Comment: What have you tried? Please try to format your question to be more readable. Include more information so the question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

- on Page 2, create a dynamic action on `P2_CODE` item which fires when event = Change.
- set "True" action to "Execute Server-side Code" in PL/SQL language; code itself will be

  ```
  apex_util.set_session_state('P3_VALUE', :P2_CODE);
  ```

  - items to submit will be set to `P2_CODE`
- create a button Page 2 which will redirect to Page 3; no additional changes should be made
- run the page

  - enter some value into `P2_CODE`
  - push the button
  - `P3_VALUE` should contain `P2_CODE`'s contents

---

In my opinion, too much job for something that could be done in a simpler manner.